# Communication between c# app and javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#

i have a c# .net (4.7.2) application, and javascript file with function. I'm trying to call that function from my c# app, pass parameter to the function and get the returned value. Is it possible?
Thanks.

My JavaScript function (Get place and return current time):

```
function getTime(place) 
{ 

        const options = {
              timeZone: place,
              year: 'numeric',
              month: 'numeric',
              day: 'numeric',
              hour: 'numeric',
              minute: 'numeric',
              second: 'numeric'
        }
        formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options)
        formatter.format(new Date())
        return formatter.format().toLocaleUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is executed on the browser or on the server in Node.js. How are you using it?

Comment: why not just re-write it in C#? It's simple enough.

Comment: Try putting the function in the head section of Site.Master

Comment: I can't tell if your intent is to simply run javascript from c# or if you are trying to mix client-side and server-side processing, but if it is the former you can execute javascript with the V8 engine or the Chakra engine  ([samples here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Chakra-Samples/tree/master/ChakraCore%20Samples))